# Не нахожу причину почему не работает z-index

Tags: html, css

Не могу найти в чём ошибка, пожалуйста если не сложно вот ссылка 'https://codepen.io/Khasan_Alimov/pen/xxRWobo?editors=1100' на кодпен где вы можете подробно посмотреть и попробовать решить эту проблему.

```js
const arr = [{
    menuName: "Accessories",
    stock: 345,
    title: "Accessories of different types",
    img: 'https://tbsnews.net/sites/default/files/styles/big_2/public/images/2020/04/11/gentleman-man-accessories-sunglasses-wallpaper-preview.jpg?itok=xbyIOxlm&timestamp=1586590381',
    submenu: ["For phones", "For clothes", "For cars", "For home", "Another"]
  },
  {
    menuName: "Clothes",
    stock: 180,
    title: "Clothes for everyone",
    img: 'https://www.wellandgood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Stocksy-folded-clothes-Alita-Ong.jpg',
    submenu: ["T-shirts", "Sweaters", "Trousers", "Shorts", "Shoe", "Underwear"]
  },
  {
    menuName: "Toys",
    stock: 1100,
    title: "Kids toys",
    img: 'https://flaircarsdecors.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/toys.jpg',
    submenu: ["For boy", "For girl"]
  },
  {
    menuName: "Furniture",
    stock: 730,
    title: "Furniture for home and office",
    img: 'https://www.comfortfurniture.com.sg/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/featured-choices-of-living-room-furniture-showroom-comfort-furniture.jpg',
    submenu: ["Office", "Living room", "Kitchen", "Children's room", "Bedroom"]
  },
  {
    menuName: "Foods",
    stock: 150,
    title: "Tasty food",
    img: 'https://www.helpguide.org/wp-content/uploads/table-with-grains-vegetables-fruit-768.jpg',
    submenu: ["For breakfast", "For lunch", "For dinner"]
  },
  {
    menuName: "Electronics",
    stock: 200,
    title: "Electronics and appliances",
    img: 'https://tinuiti.com/wp-content/uploads/legacysitecontent/cpcs/posts_01/2019/05/28142626/amazon-electronics-homepage.png.png',
    submenu: ["Phones", "TV", "Photography", "Computers", "Office electronics", "Kitchen appliances"]
  },
  {
    menuName: "Building tools",
    stock: 460,
    title: "All building tools",
    img: 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/leather-building-belt-working-tools-wooden-board-mainten-maintenance-concept-83564082.jpg',
    submenu: ["Measuring", "Hammers", "Spatulas", "Brushes", "Painting tools"]
  }
];



arr.forEach(item => {

  let catalogContainer = document.querySelector('#catalogContainer');
  let skils = '';
  item.submenu.forEach(skil => {
    skils += `<span>${skil}</span> `;
  })

  let catalog = document.createElement('div');
  catalog.className = 'catalog';

  catalog.innerHTML += `
      <a href="#">
        <p>${item.menuName}</p>
      </a>
      <div class="submenuContainer">
        <p>${item.title}</p>
      </div>
  `;

  catalogContainer.appendChild(catalog);
});

// <p>Age: ${item.stock}</p>
//       <p>Profession: ${item.title}</p>
//       <p>Skils: ${skils}</p>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}

#catalogContainer {
  border: solid 1px #80CBC4;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5% 4%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#logo_block {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #80CBC4;
  background: url(https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wooden-background_24972-623.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.1588707983.1617321600) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#logo_block a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00BFA5;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#catalogContainer .catalog:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #80CBC4;
}

#catalogContainer .catalog {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#catalogContainer .catalog:hover {
  background-color: rgba(128, 203, 196, 1);
}

#catalogContainer .catalog a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00796B;
}

#catalogContainer .catalog a p {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.submenuContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*   display: none; */
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #80CBC4;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 0 0.4rem 0.4rem 0;
  border: solid 1px #80CBC4;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

#catalogContainer .catalog:hover .submenuContainer {
  /*   display: block; */
  right: -195px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="catalogContainer">
  <div id="logo_block">
    <a href="#">Logo</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Добавьте сюда воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: а какая именно проблема с z-index? И почему ты думаешь, что проблема именно с ним?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько я понял, Вы хотели реализовать вот так вот.
Дело было не только в z-index у элемента который выезжает. Так же надо было добавить белый фон элементам которые сверху. Т.к. изначально он прозрачный.

```js
const arr = [{
    menuName: "Accessories",
    stock: 345,
    title: "Accessories of different types",
    img: 'https://tbsnews.net/sites/default/files/styles/big_2/public/images/2020/04/11/gentleman-man-accessories-sunglasses-wallpaper-preview.jpg?itok=xbyIOxlm&timestamp=1586590381',
    submenu: ["For phones", "For clothes", "For cars", "For home", "Another"]
  },
  {
    menuName: "Clothes",
    stock: 180,
    title: "Clothes for everyone",
    img: 'https://www.wellandgood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Stocksy-folded-clothes-Alita-Ong.jpg',
    submenu: ["T-shirts", "Sweaters", "Trousers", "Shorts", "Shoe", "Underwear"]
  },
  {
    menuName: "Toys",
    stock: 1100,
    title: "Kids toys",
    img: 'https://flaircarsdecors.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/toys.jpg',
    submenu: ["For boy", "For girl"]
  },
  {
    menuName: "Furniture",
    stock: 730,
    title: "Furniture for home and office",
    img: 'https://www.comfortfurniture.com.sg/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/featured-choices-of-living-room-furniture-showroom-comfort-furniture.jpg',
    submenu: ["Office", "Living room", "Kitchen", "Children's room", "Bedroom"]
  },
  {
    menuName: "Foods",
    stock: 150,
    title: "Tasty food",
    img: 'https://www.helpguide.org/wp-content/uploads/table-with-grains-vegetables-fruit-768.jpg',
    submenu: ["For breakfast", "For lunch", "For dinner"]
  },
  {
    menuName: "Electronics",
    stock: 200,
    title: "Electronics and appliances",
    img: 'https://tinuiti.com/wp-content/uploads/legacysitecontent/cpcs/posts_01/2019/05/28142626/amazon-electronics-homepage.png.png',
    submenu: ["Phones", "TV", "Photography", "Computers", "Office electronics", "Kitchen appliances"]
  },
  {
    menuName: "Building tools",
    stock: 460,
    title: "All building tools",
    img: 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/leather-building-belt-working-tools-wooden-board-mainten-maintenance-concept-83564082.jpg',
    submenu: ["Measuring", "Hammers", "Spatulas", "Brushes", "Painting tools"]
  }
];



arr.forEach(item => {

  let catalogContainer = document.querySelector('#catalogContainer');
  let skils = '';
  item.submenu.forEach(skil => {
    skils += `<span>${skil}</span> `;
  })

  let catalog = document.createElement('div');
  catalog.className = 'catalog';

  catalog.innerHTML += `
      <a href="#">
        <p>${item.menuName}</p>
      </a>
      <div class="submenuContainer">
        <p>${item.title}</p>
      </div>
  `;

  catalogContainer.appendChild(catalog);
});

// <p>Age: ${item.stock}</p>
//       <p>Profession: ${item.title}</p>
//       <p>Skils: ${skils}</p>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}

#catalogContainer {
  border: solid 1px #80CBC4;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5% 4%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
}

#logo_block {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #80CBC4;
  background: url(https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wooden-background_24972-623.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.1588707983.1617321600) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#logo_block a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00BFA5;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#catalogContainer .catalog:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #80CBC4;
}

#catalogContainer .catalog {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background-color: white
}

#catalogContainer .catalog:hover {
  background-color: rgba(128, 203, 196, 1);
}

#catalogContainer .catalog a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00796B;
}

#catalogContainer .catalog a p {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.submenuContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*   display: none; */
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #80CBC4;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 0 0.4rem 0.4rem 0;
  border: solid 1px #80CBC4;
  transition: 1s;
  z-index: -1
}

#catalogContainer .catalog:hover .submenuContainer {
  /*   display: block; */
  right: -195px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="catalogContainer">
  <div id="logo_block">
    <a href="#">Logo</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: чем твой код отличается от кода в вопросе?

Comment: @Grundy, `z-index: -1`)

Comment: Добавь пояснение в ответ, что именно поменял и почему не работало

Comment: ну так я сразу же написал, что дело не только в z-index, но и в фоне элемента. )

Comment: Сейчас два кода выглядят одинаково. Что именно поменялось и почему - неизвестно. Это нужно поправить.

Comment: Чтобы отредактировать ответ используй кнопку [edit] под ответом